# Handsontable scroll issues when HOT div height 100%

Tags: handsontable

I am trying to place the HOT element with (height:100%) inside *position:fixed* container. 
But the vertical scrolling does not work - only blank rows in FF39, GC44, and IE11.

I have also tried to set dynamically the height of HOT element to the values of parent container, e.g.

```
    var ex = $('#example').parent();
    $('#example').height(ex.height());
```

It works fine in GC and FF, but there are issues with scrolling in IE11. If you move the vertical scrollbar to the bottom, it shows the last row at ~66700. But the last row number should be 100000.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://handsontable.com/dist/handsontable.full.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="http://handsontable.com/dist/handsontable.full.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div style="position:fixed;top:20px;bottom:0;left:0;right:0; overflow:hidden; border: 1px solid green">
     <div  style="position:fixed; top:40px;left:5px;right:5px;bottom:5px;border: 1px solid red">
         <div id="example" style="overflow:auto; height:100%"></div>
     </div>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var data = Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(100000, 10);
    var container = document.getElementById('example');
    var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
       data: data,
       rowHeaders: true,
       colHeaders: true,
       stretchH: 'all',
       contextMenu: true
    });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know any CSS/layout tricks how to get Handsontable work correctly when using 100% of space of the parent container?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wasn't aware of that bug but to be honest I never use `height:100%`. Instead, why don't you manually calculate the height using the offset:

```
let height = $(window).height() - $("#hot-container").offset().top;
```

And if you want it to always keep the 100% height, even on resize, then add:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    hotInstance.updateSettings({
        height: $(window).height() - $("#hot-container").offset().top;
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for hint.  Setting the fixed height property fixes the problem in other browsers except IE11. Scrollbar position does not correspond to the visible rows when number of rows is approx. > 66000.

Comment: yeah...IE is never a good browser for web development. You can try posting this as a bug in the github page.